# Signed extension shows up as "could not be verified for use in Firefox"

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am trying to install the signed Firefox extension programmatically.
As of now I have tried to installed it by using ***windows registry*** but it is not installing in this case.

Then I have tried to installed by copying the xpi file to ***%appdata%\Mozilla\Extensions{id}\*** and ***%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\hsqut0ez.default\extensions\*** location. Extension get installed but it is disabled and browser shows up a message as **"Mozilla Firefox Extension could not be verified for use in Firefox and has been disabled."**.

When I install the extension by dragging it onto the Firefox window it gets installed fine and does NOT show the message.

Can anyone know how to installed signed extension programmatically into the the Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that you want side-loading when [uploading to AMO](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution#Unlisted_add-ons).